# Preceding "thousand [noun]" with an article

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

I have seen writers use phrases such as

> **a** thousand novels

and, in song

> **a** thousand years

preceding it with articles. I've known that articles precede, only, single concrete noun.
Why not in these cases? Is there a grammatical reason that can be explained reasonably or not?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does it imply that _a thousand years_ as a package?

Comment: [**thousands** or **a thousand**](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/thousand) "a large number or amount of people or things"

Comment: What is your definition of 'concrete'? Can you give examples of what you consider to be concrete nouns and other types (non-concrete)?

Comment: Concrete nouns name people, places, or things that you can touch, see, hear, smell, or taste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both of your cases

> **a** thousand = **one** thousand

which is used **metaphorically** to mean a **long time**. **Thousand** is a **collective** or **counting** noun meaning 1,000 years. Other collective nouns are

> a **herd** of cows
>   a **school** of fish
>   a **pod** of whales

they signify any number of items, however, the noun itself is treated as a **single** object.

**A thousand** also gets used as a **metaphor** for many things thought of collectively

> The problems of pest control have been around for **a thousand** years
>   The problems of pest control have been around for **thousands** of years

**The thousands** would refer to many **individual** items

> **The thousands** of immigrants that came through Ellis Island...
>   **The many** immigrants that came through Ellis Island...

Comment: I'm kinda confused with the definition that you gave it to _a thousand_. But now I noticed after you said _a thousand_ is a noun, that a thousand has to be followed with an article, however, is not _a thousand_ an abstract noun, therefore, it has to be without articles? You may say it has its definition metaphorically, but that really won't help me to understand this sentence _He read a thousand novels_. Does it mean **a long time**? I don't think so. So can you help me to know if you know, why a thousand is a concrete noun? I have learned that all numbers are abstract. Thank you for helping.

Comment: Why do you think abstract nouns can't take articles?  I see this belief in many places, but it is not correct; there are times when abstract nouns do take articles.  It might help for you to think of *a thousand* as "the amount of one thousand".  "A thousand" is not always metaphorical - for example, if we say "There are a thousand servants in the Emperor's palace", we mean there are literally 1000 servants.  On the other hand, if we say "I will love you for a thousand years", that is presumably metaphorical, or *poetic license*, since nobody literally lives for 1000 years.

Comment: I don't believe actually it has to be the case, but this has a philosophical answer. Things that you can't see, you can't count. Tues, articles can't precede an abstract noun. If you have a contrast example, I would like to read. And thanks for helping.

Comment: @Ali are you thinking something along the line of there is a difference between "**a** thousand" and "**the** thousand**s**" (contrived example, but trying to see where you are coming from)?

Comment: Yeah. Now, after you've told me that **thousand** is a noun by itself, I can think on the syntax of the language and its semantics in a different way. I will tell you what differs them. **A** thousand is a singular, I look at it as a box that envelope 1's of thing, and **a** what determines the indeterminacy of 1's of things while **the** thousand**s** phrase seems unclear meaningfully, but it means 2000 and more of a specific thing.

Comment: @Ali Don't mark the answer as accepted unless you have 100% confidence that your enquiry has been fully solved.

Comment: @Ali - Using articles doesn't necessarily have to do with counting things, though.  For example, you can't literally touch or count the abstract noun "beauty", but it is perfectly acceptable to say "*The beauty* of this solution is that..." because we're referring to not just any beauty, but the specific beauty that exists in this particular case.  Likewise, you can't literally touch or count an [exercise](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exercise), but it is fine to say "*An exercise* of state power" because it refers to any member of the group "exercises of state power".

Comment: @Ali I've posted additional examples

Comment: @Ali You wrote "a philosophical answer" a few comments back. Is an *answer* not an abstract thing as well? By the way, Peter was saying that *a thousand years* is a long time (though possibly not literal) not that *a thousand* by itself is a reference to time.

Comment: @Ali Here's another example related to a previous comment. *Beauty* is often an abstract noun and you're right we wouldn't ever say "A beauty is in the eye of the beholder". But the word *beauty* also can be used to mean a specific instance of something beautiful. And in that case we would say "That nice car sure is a beauty."

Answer (score 1):

A thousand years is a compound noun with a (determiner meaning one) + a noun (thousand which is a cardinal number) + a plural noun (years).

The *a* has nothing to do with years as it modifies thousand meaning *one*.

Thousand is a [**noun modifier**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/noun_modifier) which has the following definition:

> (grammar) a noun which is used attributively to modify or qualify
>   another noun, in a different way to an adjective. For example, in
>   railway station, railway is used as a modifier to describe what kind
>   of station it is.

A *noun modifier* doesn't take the plural form as adjective doesn't have the plural form. That's why the noun *thousand* is not taking the plural form in *two thousand years* and *three thousand years*.

The most important thing is the word *a* modifies *thousand*, not *years* as *two* and *three* do in the above examples. And *thousand* modifies *years* making *years* plural.

Note: There are a few exceptions where a noun modifier takes the plural form, i.e. a *sports car*, *sports news*, etc. But it is disputable whether the word sports is truly in the plural form.

[Wiktionary]